# siyamed android-satellite-menu 180 degrees

Tags: android, menu, satellite

I managed to make the satellites to expand at 180 degrees, but at the end of the animation the satellites reset and take position for 90 degrees, the rest of them disappear.
I found a centered version on github but it has the same bug.

Link to library : https://github.com/siyamed/android-satellite-menu/

Did someone manage to make 180 degree menu using this library?

Comment: I have never used this library. Your question did not get much attention, in part because you posted no code showing how you tried to do what you wanted. Since this library does not appear to be maintained anymore (no updates in 3 years), I would suggest that you find [another radial menu implementation](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/138).